# White Dyno BMX bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

How do I find out what year my Dyno bmx bike is? It was purchased around 84-85. There is no serial number anywhere on the bike. I have thoroughly looked all over the bike. I'm also trying to find out if it is a Compe or GT.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles Exchange. Identification of an older bicycle is challenging without pictures, especially any logos, etc. the shape of the frame, the details of lugs, components are all needed for the user base to help. Can you provide these by adding images? You can edit this question to add them.

Comment: Go take a look over at BMX Museum and see what it looks most like: https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?company%5B0%5D=32&year-start=1985&year-end=1985